# Are CACHEDIR.TAG and .nobackup evaluated differently?

Tags: backup, borgbackup, cache-directory

What should we keep in mind when using [CACHEDIR.TAG](https://bford.info/cachedir/) and .nobackup?

Are these synonyms, or should we expect that programs handle these differently?

Comment: Looked in `man --global-apropos 'CACHEDIR.TAG'`. Compare evaluation in [`tar`'s many exclude options](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html). `--exclude-caches` relies specifically on *well-formed* `CACHEDIR.TAG` files. `--exclude-tag='.nobackup'` can be used via the generalized "tag file" concept, which does not specifically mention `.nobackup`. Think I prefer `--exclude-vcs-ignores`, or the generalized `--exclude-ignore='ignorefile'` outside repositories. Note that `man --global-apropos '.gitignore'` (on my system) brings up support in `ag`, `cloc`, `rg`, `tree`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you should be asking is "do these filenames have any special meaning at all for my specific backup configuration?"

Apparently [BorgBackup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) has an option `--exclude-caches` which will automatically verify the signature of the `CACHEDIR.TAG` file wherever it's found and if it is correct, ignore the entire contents of the directory and all its sub-directories.

With some quick Googling on `.nobackup`, there appears to be no special support for it in BorgBackup, given that it's usually used like

```
borg recreate --exclude-if-present .nobackup /data/borg-backup
```

i.e. `.nobackup` is used as a parameter for the `--exclude-if-present` option, with no *inherent* special meaning for the filename.

The BorgBackup documentation describes these options like this:

> `--exclude-caches`    exclude directories that contain a CACHEDIR.TAG file (http://www.bford.info/cachedir/spec.html)
>
> `--exclude-if-present NAME`   exclude directories that are tagged by containing a filesystem object with the given NAME

Since both options are about excluding a directory if the specified file is in it, and `--exclude-caches` must by specification exclude that directory and all subdirectories, I must assume that `--exclude-if-present NAME` would have exactly the same effect, and that Borg documentation assumes that when a directory is excluded, it is understood without saying that all its subdirectories are excluded too.

So other than the content check on CACHEDIR.TAG, these options are effectively synonymous.

**If you don't use the appropriate options, neither of these files have any special meaning.**

If you use `--exclude-caches`, then validly-formed CACHEDIR.TAG files should cause the directory and its subdirectories be excluded, according to the linked specification.

If you use `--exclude-if-present .nobackup`, only the name of the file is checked: there is no specification for file contents, so false positives are theoretically more likely. But given the self-evident meaning of the filename, I don't think the risk is too great in practice.

You should run e.g. `locate CACHEDIR.TAG` and `locate .nobackup` as root *on your own system(s)* to evaluate how much benefit either of those options would provide to you. On my personal system, I see some programs (`fontconfig`, `man` and `plocate`) seem to have marked their caches with `CACHEDIR.TAG` files automatically, but none seem to have used `.nobackup`.

Sadly, the really big caches like Firefox's, Thunderbird's, Google Chrome's and Google Earth's don't seem to be automatically marked using either convention.

On the other hand, `touch .nobackup` is simple and needs no special knowledge. To create a `CACHEDIR.TAG` file, you'll need at least:

```
echo "Signature: 8a477f597d28d172789f06886806bc55" > CACHEDIR.TAG
```

So if you need to teach your users to maintain the marker files manually, it might be easier to teach them to create `.nobackup` files than valid `CACHEDIR.TAG`s.

On the other hand, if you can provide them (and/or yourself) a script (or similar "canned procedure") for marking a directory as to be excluded from backups, the difference in manual effort would be insignificant.